# Change Data Capture Redshift

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table

DAY 1

| ID | amount | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 12-02-2020 |
| 2 | 15 | 12-02-2020 |
| 3 | 20 | 12-02-2020 |
| 4 | 25 | 12-02-2020 |

I did a sum of the amount on day one which turns out to be 70

Now next day I have few more rows where the amount is UPDATED an APPENDED

New tables looks like this

DAY 2

| ID | amount | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 12-02-2020 |
| 2 | 20 | 13-02-2020 |
| 3 | 20 | 12-02-2020 |
| 4 | 25 | 12-02-2020 |
| 5 | 30 | 13-02-2020 |
| 6 | 35 | 14-02-2020 |

Now if you see the ID 2 has new updates amount which is 20 earlier 15
and it has new data from dates 13 and 14 on ID 5 and 6

Can I just run a query where it will only process the changed data and add it to the
previous sum
so like 30+35+5(as only 5 increased from the last value)

```
 total = 70
```

Mainly to process changed data

Comment: I am unclear on what your question is.  Perhaps you could express something as a question.  Be clear on what the before and after data looks like.

Comment: I understand you're trying to track the changes in your data. In that case you should change your database model, as the model you have right now is not able to do what you want.

Comment: If you want to do that, you cannot store your data in such manner. You should have separated it by date and its corresponding amount. If this is the "after processed" table data, how does the source being obtained for the update? From a different table(s)? If there's a different table, how is the data being stored in that different table?

Comment: @FaNo_FN yes, so we have a third party software which does it.So what happens is  the new data is pushed everyday from the third party .They have access to our tables where they drop and create the new table again for us.Its like a total overwrite of the last data.so if on day 1 one of my customers had some balance of 60 USD and he paid 40 the next day then the new table will have outstanding balance of 20 and it will not show me the previous historical data. the problem is that its an over write all the time,How do I process the only data which is new.Beacuse we run the entire table everytime

Comment: @RobertoC.Rodriguez-Hidalgo A third party software which does it.what happens is the new data is pushed everyday from the third party .They have access to our tables where they drop and create the new table again for us.Its like a total overwrite of the last data.so if on day 1 one of my customers had some balance of 60 USD and he paid 40 the next day then the new table will have outstanding balance of 20 and it will not show me the previous historical data. the problem is that its an over write all the time,How do I process the only data which is new.Beacuse we run the entire table everytime

Comment: When you said third party software, it's not like a different company doing the data update right?

Comment: @FaNo_FN its a diff company which makes that for us. Like they push the data from us . So they drop our previous tables and create a new table from scratch which has both the updated data and the appended data.

Comment: I see, then how do they re-populate the data once they drop and re-create the table? I'm guessing there's a reference table that keep all the transactions; and probably record of each customer+amount+date of transaction. That is where you should look at. OR, you can request the company to store historical data.. maybe before dropping the table, insert the data to a different table then only drop and re-populate.

Comment: @FaNo_FN so it is also done by third party . They keep the reference tables with them , when they see a change in the tables and some data they do that on their side , all the appends and update. so in new table which will be created at our end might have a diff value for ID-2 from last day . but we wouldn't know what was last data so we process the entire data again and again everything we have an update and append

Comment: @FaNo_FN Yeah, my question is that even if I ask the company or we create the snapshot of the data everyday in S3 and then the company sends us the new data from which we can find out the diff from the previous data. I would want to ask for suggestion on how can I process it?  How can I only process the new updated and appended data . Is there a way I can reduce the query process time because we process all the data everytime we have an update or append

Comment: @AdityaVerma I think you should ask the third party for the history table. On the other hand, if you have admin access to the database you can create a history table and a stored procedure that could run everyday in order to achieve the current status of your data, in a way you can query both previous day and current day data to get the differences.

Comment: @RobertoC.Rodriguez-Hidalgo, I think they have no problem in getting the historical data.. their concern is if they have the historical data, what is the query to compare between the last updated with the newly appended data? and, I guess one with a good performance?

Comment: @FaNo_FN Yes you are right getting the historical data is not an issue , the concern is that if I only process the new appened and updated data that what is the dependency of the previous data. like an AVG where I would still need the numbers of rows to take out the average which will not be true if I only process the new data. if that makes sense ? Also if I am processing the whole data again it hits the query performance badly because I am processing all of it again and again

Comment: @RobertoC.Rodriguez-Hidalgo  , FANO is right , we can  get the historical data is not an issue , the concern is that if I only process the new appened and updated data that what is the dependency of the previous data. like an AVG where I would still need the numbers of rows to take out the average which will not be true if I only process the new data. if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

This will very much depend on how the historical data will be provided.

This example requires additional `Day` column in the historical data table AND that you're using a MySQL version that supports `LAG()` (e.g. MySQL v8+ OR MariaDB 10.3+). Let's assume that it's possible for the historical data table to be like this:

| ID | Amount | Date | Day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 2020-02-12 | 1 |
| 2 | 15 | 2020-02-12 | 1 |
| 3 | 20 | 2020-02-12 | 1 |
| 4 | 25 | 2020-02-12 | 1 |
| 1 | 10 | 2020-02-12 | 2 |
| 2 | 20 | 2020-02-13 | 2 |
| 3 | 20 | 2020-02-12 | 2 |
| 4 | 25 | 2020-02-12 | 2 |
| 5 | 30 | 2020-02-13 | 2 |
| 6 | 35 | 2020-02-14 | 2 |

.. then maybe a query like this:

```
SELECT Day, 
       SUM(amount) AS Total,
       SUM(amount)-LAG(SUM(amount)) OVER (ORDER BY Day) AS diff
FROM historical_data 
GROUP BY Day
ORDER BY Day;
```

OR (in for MariaDB):

```
SELECT Day, Total,
       Total-LAG(Total) OVER (ORDER BY Day) AS Diff
 FROM
(SELECT Day, 
       SUM(amount) AS Total
FROM historical_data 
GROUP BY Day) A;
```

This will return result like:

| Day | Total | diff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 70 |  |
| 2 | 140 | 70 |

I was following an example from [this site](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-lag-function/) on how to use `LAG()` to get the row data value above it an using them to subtract the `SUM(amount)` value for that day.

[Here's a demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4aff3014e63813d24114324144e7a288) of the experiment.